# Continuous horizontal scrolling MKMapView

Tags: ios, scroll, mkmapview, pan

Is there a way to have a Google MKMapView on iOS able so you can "continually" scroll horizontally? Android allows you to continually pan left or right. It makes it easy for zooming in on countries in the Pacific. The Maps application on my iPhone doesn't seem to have this behaviour but I was hoping the API would allow me to configure it somehow.